# iphone:How to track user location using GPS in iphone?

Tags: ios4

I want to develop track user application which track the user's position each & every time using GPS so please provide me any link or examples materials etc

Thanks

Comment: This is a very general question. You're much more likely to get useful answers if you explain what resources you've checked, and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Use CoreLocation Framework. Look for 'LocateMe' sample project under Samples in developer.apple.com

Comment: No its not useful i want to track user location whenever its position is changed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cllocation` and also `cllocation didupdate` location method it will update  user's location and will display current `latitude`, `longitude`, `altitude` etc.

Check [this](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) and [this](http://programmersweb.blogspot.com/2011/07/using-core-location-to-determine-your.html).